# Cumulative count within group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a column that contains a cumulative count of another column.

My data:

```
df <- data.frame(brand = c("A","B","C","A","A","B","A","A","B","C"))
```

And this is my expected output:

```
    |Brand |  Count  |
    |:-----|--------:|
    |A     |        1|
    |B     |        1|
    |C     |        1|
    |A     |        2|
    |A     |        3|
    |B     |        2|
    |A     |        4|
    |A     |        5|
    |B     |        3|
    |C     |        2|
```

I have tried cumsum but it doesn't accept strings or factors:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Brand) %>%
  mutate(Count = cumsum(Brand))
```

Edit: For bonus points it would be great if the solution could be used on database tables also (SQL Server)

Answer (score 7):

We can create the column with `rowid` of 'brand'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
 df %>%
    mutate(Count = rowid(brand))
```

---

Or use a `row_number` after grouping by 'brand'

```
df %>%
    group_by(brand) %>%
    mutate(Count = row_number())
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Count := rowid(brand)]
```

Comment: You are always so quick! Do you have a way that we could do this on a database table? `row_number()` doesn't work

Comment: Also there are 3m rows in my dataframe. Your second solution has been running for 15 minutes with no output yet....

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe  At the time I answered the question, the database part was not in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To give an update on this issue:

The second solution by @akrun

```
myDF |>
  group_by(myGroup) |> 
  mutate(Count = row_number())
```

worked for me and happened very fast (for >80 000 rows). Not on a database, but might still be good to know for some people that it works and is fast.